# How to know the count of lables or fields in a particular screen using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium

Is there any way to find the count of fields or lables in a particular screen using selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery('span').size()` will give you the number of span elements in the page.

Answer (score 1):

Reference from Selenium IDE:

> `storeXpathCount`: Returns the number of nodes that match the specified xpath, eg. "//table" would give the number of tables.
>
> `storeCssCount`: Returns the number of nodes that match the specified selector, eg. "css=table" would give the number of tables.